# Draw thick, feathered line with variable thickness in plane C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, spline, heightmap

I'm creating a heightmap painting tool which uses a spline to paint the heightmap with a value from 0 to 1. The spline consists of several points each of which has different thickness (size/width) and this gets interpolated. The tool paints a projection of the path on the heightmap with a thickness specified by the user, multiplied by each point's size and a feather specified by the user. So far I've managed to implement everything and my implementation works like that:

- Takes two points (i and i+1) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1iqr.jpg)
- Finds the perpendicular line to (points[i+1].position-points[i].position) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d11u4.jpg)
- Fills the rectangle defined by the start and end points of the perpendicular lines (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGveD.jpg) using a feather.

To fill these rectangles I draw multiple lines using a variation of Bresenham's line algorithm:

```
public void drawLine(Point fromPoint, Point toPoint, float fromValue, float toValue, ref float[,] grid)
{
    int x0 = fromPoint.x, y0 = fromPoint.y, x1 = toPoint.x, y1 = toPoint.y;
    int dx = Mathf.Abs(x1 - x0), sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
    int dy = -Mathf.Abs(y1 - y0), sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;
    int err = dx + dy, e2;
    int x = x0, y = y0;
    Vector2 target = new Vector2(x1 - x0, y1 - y0);
    while(true)
    {
        Vector2 current = new Vector2(x - x0, y - y0);
        float addValue = Mathf.Lerp(fromValue, toValue, current.magnitude / target.magnitude);

        plot(x, y, addValue, 1f, ref grid);
        if (sample) grid[x, y] = supersample(x, y, ref grid);

        if (x == x1 && y == y1) break;
        e2 = 2 * err;
        if (e2 > dy)
        {
            err += dy;
            x += sx;
        } else if (e2 < dx)
        {
            err += dx;
            y += sy;
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good! The problem however comes when one of the points on the spline has a different size than the other points. Since this algorithm does not draw an anti-aliased line, the drawn shape starts to look jaggy. This happens because I draw a line for each pixel of the bigger point's perpendicular line and map their endpoints to the smaller point's perpendicular line. So basically lines start to overlap each other around the more narrow point.
I tried to draw a graphic to visualize the problem:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Us5flFf.jpg]

So my final result looks like that:
[image: 2]

You can see how the feathered part is very jagged.

I tried to use Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm to draw the lines but that causes gaps to appear between the pixels and the fill becomes inconsistent. 
So far only applying Gausian blur makes things look better but it doesn't fix the problem completely and it's heavy so I dropped that option too.

I really need to implement this without using any libraries so any suggestions on how to go about tackling this issues are very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: @TaW It's a Unity project. I'm writing the values to a float[,] array.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like, if more than one line is drawing to a particular point, you want to add "less" for each line.  The more lines drawn to a particular point, the "less" each line should affect it.

Something like... (uncompiled example)

```
int[,] gridDrawCount = new int[grid.GetLength(0),grid.GetLength(1)];
```

...

```
//inside the loop
gridDrawCount[x,y]++;
plot(x, y, addValue/gridDrawCount[x,y], 1f, ref grid);  //I added the divide by part
```

It's possible you may want to, instead of doing the division inside the loop as shown above, iterate through your grid AFTER the loop, and THEN each value divide by the gridDrawCount value(watch out for div by zero)-  should give a slightly different, possibly more consistent effect, but will obviously be slower.

Comment: I actually went with a similar approach yesterday:
Instead of having the line's color predefined I define each pixel's color when the line algorithm draws it. I project the pixel's position on the center line that connects point i and point i+1 and then measure the distance between those pixels to calculate the feather. I add the drawn pixels to another array so I don't have to make these calculations again if the next line goes over the same pixels but even without that array, it won't overdraw because it would just recalculate the same value for the pixel. Sadly, the pixels are still jagged.

Comment: still jagged:  I suspect this is due to the fact that you don't do any anti-aliasing in your computations.   Does it at least show the feather properly along the length now.  (good move using the separate array!)

Comment: Down and dirty anti-aliasing can be achieved by drawing a SECOND line, for each "normal" line, at half alpha, and offsetting the source, or destination of the line, by 1 pixel.  (or divide alpha by 3, and draw two extra lines with offsets of +1, and -1, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to my problem. It's not the most optimal one but it's working for me right now.

In my question I explained that the algorithm draws a line for each pixel of the point's perpendicular line to a mapped out pixel (based on percentage) of the next point's perpendicular line. That caused overdraw so Glurth proposed that I keep an array of points that I've already drawn to. That method actually caused even more jagginess since the lines didn't always draw the right value to the right pixel (because of the mapping - it's a float percent which has to be rounded to get the pixel from the next perpendicular line).

So what I did was to project each pixel from the current drawing line onto the center line that connects the points and measure the distance between the line pixel and the projected one. Based on that I calculate the feather.

### [image: Project pixel onto center line]

Of course, since the spline path is projected onto a pixel grid, aliasing occurs and my solution to that (for now) is to use a Gausian blur with 1f radius on the drawn pixels to smooth out the result.

The whole thing is not too slow and it gives a fairly good result which is sufficient for now. Since the ends of the perpendicular lines of each two points form a polygon, I can triangulate it (manually set the triangles, I don't need no complicated triangulation algorithms) and fill it like that instead of drawing multiple lines which often draw over the same pixel several times.

Hope that has been useful. If somebody decided to try my method, I'd suggest that they jump to the triangulation right away and not use line drawing. I had line drawing to start with so I utilized it but it's not optimal in my opinion.